# How should I Microsoft Edge Console errors? And few doubts in the code

Tags: javascript, html

What do the numbers in the parenthesis mean?

For ex, audio.js(1,1)
.[image]

Oh yeah, this code is to autoplay music in my webpage.
    HTML CODE:

```
<head>
<title> Customized audio web page </title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

These links are like the libraries for the plus, minus and speaker symbols.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
```

Volume control

```
<button onclick="volume_down()" style="font-size:24px;color:blue"><i class="fa fa-minus-square"></i></button>
<button onclick="volume_switch()" style="font-size:24px;color:blue"><i class="material-icons">volume_off/volume_up</i></button>
<button onclick="volume_up()" style="font-size:24px;color:blue"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></button>

<audio id="bgm" controls autoplay hidden="hidden">              
<source src="Z:\Pollution Levels\Eternal Pose.mp3"/>  

</audio>

<script src="audio.js"></script>                        

</body>
</html>
```

This code is to increase or decrease the volume in steps of 10%.

```
JavaScript Code:
var aud = document.getElementById("bgm");
aud = {vol:0.5};

function volume_up() {
    if(aud.vol=1.0)
    {aud.vol  = 1.0;}
    else
    {aud.vol += 0.1;}
}

function volume_down() {
    if(aud.vol=0.0)
    {aud.vol = 0.0;}
    else
        {aud.vol -= 0.1;}
}
```

Hey, if I store an object value, aud.vol in a variable, will the prev_vol be update when aud.vol changes (this is to restore the volume of music after unmuting).

```
function volume_switch() {
    var prev_vol = aud.vol;
    if(aud.vol>0.0)
    {aud.vol -= aud.vol;}
    else if(aud.vol=0.0)
    {aud.vol = prev_vol;}
}
```

Comment: line and character position

Comment: Hehe, yep I did, but you see, I got a syntax error on Line 1 of JS code, but I don't think there is.

Answer (score 0):

Line and character positions respectively.

Comment: I don't understand, what is wrong on line 1 of JavaScript code. Can you please once look for me?

Comment: @MdArshadAli If you show us audio.js, we might be able to help.